# How to configure ef core to have multiple tables for the different subclasses

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I use ef core.

I have a base class C with a 1 to many relation to D.
I have two sub classes C1 and C2.
I use TPC.

When doing that, D table has fields for D properties and one for the reference to C1 and one for the reference to C2.

Actually, I have many subclasses. Thus, most of the fields are references to these different sublassses.

I would prefer to have many tables for D (one per sub-class of C).

In fact, I'd like to configure it this way:

```
builder.Entity<C1>()
  .HasMany( c => c.DProperty )
  .WithOne()
  .ToTable("C1D");
builder.Entity<C2>()
  .HasMany( c => c.DProperty )
  .WithOne()
  .ToTable("C2D");
```

But it does not work. `ToTable` cannot be used here.

I tried to create differents subclasses of D: D1 and D2 and make C generic so that DProperty is of type `List<T>` (thus D1 or D2) hoping it would generate these two tables.
Does not work either.

Is there a way to do that (without copying the DProperty with its DX type in each subclass)?

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Please see: [What Do You Mean “It Doesn't Work”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147616)

Comment: Is it an option to use table-per-type instead of table-per-concrete-type?